# Using a variable with xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, xml, variables

I'm trying to use a date variable in JavaScript to reference a tag in an XML document and then return the value of an attribute called `Current` within that tag. But without success.

I'm sure I'm just missing something but can't work out what... Any help is very much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(weekscalendar) {

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

    } else {
        xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET","weeks.xml",false);
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
}

if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
}
today = dd + mm + yyyy;

xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("weeks.xml");
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName (today);

var week = x.getAttributeNode("Current").nodeValue; //the nodevalue is the week
document.write(week);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

An extract of my XML file is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Portal>
<23062013   Current="Week 13 (23/06/2013 - 29/06/2013)" Last="Week 12 (16/06/2013 - 22/06/2013)" Next="Week 14 (30/06/2013 - 06/07/2013)" />
<24062013   Current="Week 13 (23/06/2013 - 29/06/2013)" Last="Week 12 (16/06/2013 - 22/06/2013)" Next="Week 14 (30/06/2013 - 06/07/2013)" />
</Portal>
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to re–use variables to hold totally different data. *today* starts as a date object, then is assigned a string that is used as a tag name. It would be clearer to create another called say *tagName* like `var tagName = dd + mm + yyyy;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` returns a collection of elements (notice the `s`) so you have to select an element then get its attribute.

Also having  numeric tag names might be problematic

non numeric tag http://jsfiddle.net/DT64U/

numeric tag http://jsfiddle.net/DT64U/1

Comment: thanks for your suggestion Musa but it still does not work. I changed the code to use

Comment: x=xmlDoc.getElementByTagName (today);
and still it did nothing.

Comment: I also tried prefixing the tags in the XML file with the letter a and used the code x=xmlDoc.getElementByTagName ("a" + today); and still nothing - numbers should not cause a problem as the only illegal characters in XML are < and &

Comment: @ladders81 did you take a look at the links in my answer?

Comment: Hi Musa, managed to get it sorted after looking at your links... thanks very much for your help!